# Use \int\limits by default, except for inline math

Tags: math-mode, inline

How can you instruct latex to use `\int\limits` as default for `\int` except when it's in inline math mode?

Example:

In display math: `\int` is replaced by `\int\limits`

In inline math: `\int` should stay `\int`

Comment: To use `\int\limits` where? In displayed formula? Please, add an example code.

Comment: I've added an example that should answer your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just load the `amsmath` package with the option `intlimits`.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\int_0^1 \quad \displaystyle \int_0^1$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked! Since I'm using mathtools too I had to add that option there too in order not to get a name clash with amsmath.

Comment: @ndrizza - The `mathtools` package loads the `amsmath` package automatically -- no need to load both explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! I was never sure about that. - That might explain the name clash. Indeed if I remove the import nothing changes.